# Paypal checkout card issue

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox

On my website i create card token using paypal Payment Method Tokens API. My question is - **how to add checkout card button but without default card fields, instead using my card token (vault_id) saved in database when creating order**.
I tried to do it but when i am using vault_id of my card it captures money immediately and onApprove function on checkout button not triggered at all, despite success transaction there is error in script "code: undefined".
my code of creating order:

```
 const order = {
        intent: 'CAPTURE',
        purchase_units: [
            {
                amount: {
                    currency_code: 'USD',
                    value: `10.00`,
                },
            },
        ],

    };

    if (vaultId) {
        order.payment_source = {
            card: {
                vault_id: vaultId
            }
        };
    }
```

I use standard checkout.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an already-stored vault_id to trigger a payment immediately, *don't* combine that with the JS SDK. This flow is for when the payer is *not* (no longer) present.

The JS SDK has a returning payer flow. See the "**Returning payer**" tab in [the vault documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/beta/vault/during-purchase/js-sdk/cards/#link-createorderandsavecard).